# Timezone in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

It seems to be a very difficult task to set time zone based on user's current location in PHP.

I am finding it difficult to implement time zone dynamically in PHP, I am using codeigniter framework.

I found a git repository here https://github.com/tamaspap/timezones, but not able to integrate it with my codeigniter project.

Answer (score 2):

You can set timezone just using `date_default_timezone_set('timezone_name');`.The `date_default_timezone_set()` function sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in the script.

For example :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Sets timezone for `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: here is the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Placing this date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); on config.php above base url also works
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

**application/config.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```